# Highlight item in 1st ItemsControl on selection of same item inside 2nd ItemsControl and also show that selected item in a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, selection, itemscontrol

I have a list of strings in the main window class and two ItemsControl binded to same list and SelectedItem dependency property.

What i did i used Button itemtemplate for the 2nd ItemsControl and on Button Click event i am able to get the value of the selected button and then pass it to SelectedItem property and SelectedItem property is binded to the textbox.

What i want to do now is to Highlight the same item in 1st ItemsContol as well and also want backward selection.

Note: Need to use pure ItemsControl only. No other control like ListBox etc. are allowed. Also i have been asked to use ItemsControl class descendant for SelectedItem which i don't understand.

Thanks.

Comment: Use two ListBoxes and bind the SelectedItem property of one to that of the other.

Comment: @Clemens I am not allowed to use any other control then ItemsControl that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are referring to `SelectedItem` I assume that you are using a `Selector` derived control, instead of a pure `ItemsControl`.

In this case a simple solution is to set [`Selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem?view=net-5.0#remarks) to `True` on both controls and bind the `TextBox`to either one of the `SelectedItem` properties (or to the common binding source property of `SelectedItem`):

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ListBox, Path=SelectedItem}" />
  <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" 
           IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
  <ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: No i have to do it pure ItemsControl way. I have been asked to use some ItemsControl class descendant which i don't understand.

Comment: "*ItemsControl class descendant*" might mean a class derived from ItemsControl, e.g. ListBox.